# SQL query GROUP BY id filter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

THIS IS THE OUTPUT OF THE QUERY:
[image]

```
SELECT * FROM
                    ((SELECT 
                        privatemsgs.id,
                        privatemsgs.useradn,
                        privatemsgs.useraid,
                        privatemsgs.title,
                        privatemsgs.created,
                        privatemsgs.timee,
                        privatemsgs.isread,
                        u.photo AS creatorphoto,
                        privatemsgs.relatedto
                    FROM privatemsgs 
                    LEFT JOIN
                        users AS u ON(privatemsgs.useraid = u.id)
                    WHERE userbid='$myid'
                        AND relatedto=0 and bdel=1)
                    UNION
                    (SELECT
                        privatemsgs.id,
                        privatemsgs.useradn,
                        privatemsgs.useraid,
                        privatemsgs.title,
                        privatemsgs.created,
                        privatemsgs.timee,
                        privatemsgs.isread,
                        u.photo AS creatorphoto,
                        rel.relatedto
                    FROM privatemsgs AS rel
                        JOIN privatemsgs ON(rel.relatedto = privatemsgs.id)
                        LEFT JOIN
                        users AS u ON(rel.useraid = u.id)
                    WHERE rel.userbid='$myid'
                    )) privatemsgs
                    GROUP BY id
                    ORDER BY timee DESC
```

I got double id "2". first 1 with "isread = 0", second with "isread = 1".

When I added "group by id", I've got (line 2)

But i need the output to show that isread = 1 (like line 3)

How do i fix it?

Comment: Please provide the query

Comment: Hint: `MAX(isread)` and `GROUP BY id`

Comment: Post the query itself plz :D We don't know what query you're using :)

Comment: Why have you added a second row with the same id in the first place?

Comment: Good point. Id should be unique. This should be the key value, so you can't make 2 same.
By select you can get more rows with same id, but different data. This is why we need your query first.

Comment: Just my two bits: avoid names like timee, useradn, useraid etc. now you know what they mean but in 3 months you will not remember (trust me I know :)) it does not cost a lot to name columns properly and will increase your code readability greatly and will make it more understandable in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add MAX(isread) near the *. GROUP BY works only on Aggregate functions